# How change topic leader or remove partition after some broker down?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have a kafka cluster with 4 brokers and some topics with replica factor 1 and 10 partitions.
At one moment 2 of our 4 servers with the kafka cluster - fail.
So now we have 2 brokers with the same topics.
When I run the command
`./kafka_topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe`
I get this:

```
Topic:outcoming-notification-error-topic        PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 1    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 2    Leader: 4       Replicas: 4     Isr: 4
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 4    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 5    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 6    Leader: 4       Replicas: 4     Isr: 4
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
    Topic: outcoming-error-topic       Partition: 9    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
```

How can I delete Leader 2...4? Or maybe I need to delete the partition for this Leader, but how?

UPD..

Also, we use kafka_exporter for monitoring kafka with Prometheus. After 2 brokers are down, in the log of kafka_exporter, we get this error:

```
level=error msg="Cannot get oldest offset of topic outcoming-error-topic partition  10: kafka server: In the middle of a leadership election, there is currently no leader for this partition and hence it is unavailable for writes." source="kafka_exporter.go:296"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Kafka's `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` to do that. You have two ways, one is **generating a proposal of new assignments**, and the other one is [manually specifying](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_partitionassignment) the leaders for specific partitions.

---

### 1 .  Generate a proposal

The first method, as specified on the [kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_automigrate), follows this logic:

1.1  **Generate Proposed partition reassignment configuration**

First, you should create a json file such as the provided in the link. Let's name it `topics.json`.

```
{
  "topics": [{"topic": "foo1"},
            {"topic": "foo2"}],
  "version":1
}
```

This will tell kafka what are the topics you are willing to rellocate their partitions from. In the example, he wants Kafka to make a proposal for topics `foo1` and `foo2`.

With that json, call the tool and set the active broker list in the command:

```
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS 
--topics-to-move-json-file topics.json --broker-list "1,2,3,4,5" --generate
```

This will output Kafka's proposal, which you can save into another .json file. For example:

```
{
  "version":1,
  "partitions":[{"topic":"foo1","partition":2,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo1","partition":0,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo2","partition":2,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo2","partition":0,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo1","partition":1,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo2","partition":1,"replicas":[5,6]}]
}
```

You can manually modify some of the assignments, if you want to (or think it's the proper think to do, as the tool is not perfect). Save the json into a file, for example, `reassign-example.json`, which will be used in the next step.

1.2.   **Execute the Proposed partition reassignment**

Let's make Kafka execute the proposal and move the partitions. For that, execute:

```
bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS 
 --reassignment-json-file reassign-example.json --execute
```

This will execute the partition movement defined on the `reassign-example.json` file.

---

### 2 . Manual specification

The second method is fairly easier, but you must manually identify the partitions you want to reassign. For example, if you want partition 1 of topic XXX to move to brokers 5 and 6, you could create a json file (`manual-reassign.json`) such as:

```
{"version":1,"partitions":[{"topic":"XXX","partition":1,"replicas":[5,6]}]}
```

The way it's launched is the same as in the previous method:

```
bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS 
 --reassignment-json-file manual-reassign.json --execute
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! i`m create  file: 

`cat topicmove.json
{
"topics":[ {"topic": " outcoming-notification-error-topic"} ],
"version":1`

  

I`m run command : 

 `    bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topics-to-move-json-file topicmove.json --broker-list "1,2" --generate `


and get only this:

 `      Current partition replica assignment
{"version":1,"partitions":[]}
    Proposed partition reassignment configuration
{"version":1,"partitions":[]} `

Comment: Sorry for that, totally my fault! Was missing the `--execute` flag in the commands that actually repartition based on your json file. I edited the answer, hope it helps now!

Comment: im create file for reassignment - manually, run `kafka-reassignemtn-partitions.sh` with `--verify` options and got error that some reassignment for partition - failed. Example:   `Reassignment of partition outcoming-error-topic-5 failed`
But Two partition - completed  : 
`Reassignment of partition outcoming-notification-error-topic-3 completed`

Comment: Hi @Sergey and sorry for the late response (a year later!). That must be some kind of error regarding the broker which holds the failed partition. You should take a look at those broker logs, as well as zookeeper logs, to check what's the inconvience. Hope it helps bro.