# kafka broker with inconsistent data - NotLeaderForPartitionError

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a 13 node Kafka cluster and each broker has multiple disks and all topics have replication factor 3.

Broker 6 had a hardware issue and required a complete OS reload (Linux) and 2 disk replacements. Now I installed Kafka again on this node with the same broker id 6 but started to get an exception from all producers -

```
[Error 6] NotLeaderForPartitionError: ProduceResponsePayload(topic=u'amyTopic', partition=7, error=6, offset=-1)
```

I am assuming that since I am using the same broker ID, it (zookeeper? or controller broker?) is expecting data in the disk which got replaced or some other meta info that might get wiped out during OS reload.

What are the options I have to add this node back to the cluster without much disturbance to the cluster and without data loss? Should I use a new broker ID for this node and then repartition the data of every topic as we do after adding a new node? We have a lot of data (a few hundred TB) in the cluster and I am trying to avoid huge data movement caused by the repartition of data and it may choke the entire cluster. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you try to clear `partition metadata` and `broker metadata` from zookeeper? and what is your `unclean.leader.election.enable`?

Comment: this might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202261/how-change-topic-leader-or-remove-partition-after-some-broker-down?rq=1

Comment: @nipuna `unclean.leader.election.enable` is false and I had not deleted partition and broker metadata because I was afraid that it might create another issue.

Comment: @chitenderkumar Thanks for the link. I am aware of it but as mentioned in the question I want to avoid data movement because it's huge.

Comment: @NishantKumar make `unclean.leader.election.enable = true` for the topic. Then partitions will elect a leader without broker 6. [topicconfigs_unclean.leader.election.enable](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_unclean.leader.election.enable)